# How do I add background image in webpage?

Tags: html, image, flask

I want to add a background image to my webpage and also a small image next t the predict/submit button but instead of the image it just shows a broken link icon. The background image is also not showing. I made sure the image is in the same folder as my html file but no luck. This is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title> blah blah </title>
<style>
body{
   background-image:url('wheat.jpg');
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-attachment: fixed;
   background-size: cover
}    
</style>
</head>

    <center>

    <h1> WHEAT SPECIES CLASSIFICATION </h1><br>
    
    <form method="POST", action="{{url_for('home')}}">
       
       <b> compactness :  <input name="compactness" type="number" step="any" min="0" 
                          class="form-control" required> <br><br>
       
       kernel length : <input name="kernel_length" type="number" step="any" min="0" 
                       class="form-control" required> <br><br>

       width : <input name="width" type="number" step="any" min="0" class="form-control" 
               required> <br><br>            

       asymmetry coef : <input name="asymmetry_coef" type="number" step="any" min="0" 
                        class="form-control" required> <br><br>
       
       groove length : <input name="groove_length" type="number" step="any" min="0" 
                       class="form-control" required> <br><br>
       
       <input type="submit" , value='predict!' >
       
    </form>
    
    </center>
    
</body>
    
</html>
```

Edit 1: I tried the answered recommendation but now the image is enlarged too much. How do I resize the image?

[image]

Comment: Okay, you're using flask. Does it work if you access the URL of the image manually?

Comment: You mean paste the link of the image in `background-image:url('wheat.jpg');`? PS: I am new to this

Comment: I tried using the link of the image and also tried using the location of the image on my machine but no luck

Comment: Since you are using flask, you might want to check this documentation. Basically, you need to work with static files and flask wants you to put them in a specific folder. Details here: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/tutorial/static/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, when you work with Flask, the resources are looked for in "flaskProject/static", so you will have to leave your image in "flaskProject/static/img/" (creating them if necessary).

Then you can reference the resources with the relative path:

```
background-image: url({{ url_for('static', filename='img/wheat.jpg') }})
```

**Reference**: *https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/tutorial/static/

Comment: Ok but now the background image is enlarged too much. I can't even se half the image. See the edited question

Comment: Now your problem must be in the CSS, I recomend you to read the following documentation from [w3schools CSS background](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp) (more documentation about [CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/))